# Postgres, delete the known characters from a string

Tags: postgresql

I've a column name "label" in table "inventory". column label contains values where it has special characters

in the starting of the values. Any suggestions for removing the special character using the Postgres sql query.

Already tried trim and replace function but of no help.

Tried  trim and replace functions but didn't worked

String without

characters.

Comment: Use [regexp_replace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) function. Example: `select regexp_replace("label", '[^0-9a-z\s]', '', 'gi') from inventory;`. It removes all characters except letters, digits and whitespaces. You may modify the regular expression if needed.

Comment: <p><span data-sheets-value="{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;Food &amp; Beverages&quot;}" data-sheets-userformat="{&quot;2&quot;:15359,&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:0},&quot;4&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:16777215},&quot;5&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0,&quot;5&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0}},{&quot;1&quot;:0,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;7&quot;:{&quot;1&quot;:[{&quot;1&quot;:2{&quot;1&quot;:2,&quot;2&quot;:0},&quot;15&quot;:&quot;Calibri&quot;,&quot;16&quot;:9}">Food &amp; Beverages</span></p>